# Two sample t-test for proportions -- what is that?

Tags: t-test, proportion

This is a question about, um, statistical forensics.

A colleague sent me some statistical results for validation. He claims that he used a "two sample t-test" to compare percentages of a phenomenon in two groups.

At first I thought that he meant a normal test for proportions (like prop.test in R), or a z-score test, however, I was unable to replicate his p-values.

Edit: yes, I am aware of replies like [this one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/90893/why-use-a-z-test-rather-than-a-t-test-with-proportional-data#90936), stating that no, you actually can't use a t-test for proportions. So let me reformulate the question: do you know of any program that might claim to use a "two sample t-test for proportions"? Or, maybe, what other test could have been used to obtain the given p-values?

Consider the following (real) data. Below, I give the number of positives and group size.

```
Group   k   N
A      33  140
B       4    7
C      37  161
D       7   33
```

My colleague did pairwise comparisons and obtained the following p-values:

```
A vs B: p = 0.0374
C vs B: p = 0.041
D vs B: p = 0.606
```

My question: what test was used to obtained these p-values?

When I applied prop.test (z-test) from R (with Yates' correction for continuity), I got following p-values: 0.121, 0.107, 0.174. Without Yates' correction: 0.046, 0.039, 0.069 (close, but no banana).

(Of course, the simplest thing would be to ask my colleague what he did, but this is, for reasons beyond the scope of this discussion, not possible).

Comment: Surely you can find good answers to this question by searching our site for [t-test proportion](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=t-test+proportion).

Comment: Surely you are not suggesting that I didn't even bother to look for an answer first? :-) I'm too old to waste your and mine time like that. I have updated the question, maybe it is clearer now why I can't find an answer in the archives.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why use a z test rather than a t test with proportional data?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/90893/why-use-a-z-test-rather-than-a-t-test-with-proportional-data)

Comment: @XavierBourretSicotte you might have noticed that I did run the z-test (prop.test in R) and obtained different p-values, therefore z-test is not the correct answer to my question.

Comment: I played around with different (inappropriate) ways someone might try a t-test with these data. I didn't find any way that matched.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. I have read a lot about the "t-tests for proportions" discussion on diverse more or less (rather less) "scientific" pages, but what I am always missing is actually any kind of reference, where people retrieve their information from. To give a start and also to push the discussion further, please have a look at "The Appropriateness of Some Common Procedures for Testing the Equality of Two Independent Binomial Populations by Ralph B. D'agostino,Warren Chase &Albert Belanger who write" In this article we demonstrate that, even for small samples, the uncorrected chi-squ